# Compare strings in two files

Tags: windows, batch-file, scripting

I would compare strings in two file and if counted string redirect to file c, but running .bat show the error message "find paramenter format not correct".

Otherwise, anything good script design for this!  Thanks

Example strings:

File A: 1 2 3 4

File B: 1 2 3 4 5

Code:

```
for /F %%a in ( file B ) do (
  for /F %%b in ( 'find /C %%a file A' ) do (
        if [%%b]==[1] ( 
            echo %%b >> file c
        ) else (
            echo %%b >> file d
        )
    )
)
```

Comment: File names with spaces require quotes.

Comment: not only filenames with spaces, also the searchstring has to be enclosed in quotes: `... in ('find /c "%%a" "file A"') do ...`. Also `if` will be problematic with this syntax, it `%%b` contains spaces. Better use quotes too: `if "%%b"=="1"` (should be no problem here, but better get used to a generally unproblematic syntax)